# Setup webhook for push iOS notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, apple-push-notifications, webhooks

I am using an API which doesn't support direct iOS notifications instead they use webhook. When I contacted them about how to use it I got back the response

> We DO NOT support iOS push notification directly to your client apps.
>   You can make use the webhook notification to receive the update, then your script can relay or send out the notification to your clients app directly.

I am given a place to enter a URL for the webhook.

And how would I implement

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // Store the deviceToken
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    //handle push notification
}
```

What do I need to receive push notifications to my application?

Comment: What is API which you are using? What's its name?

Comment: @Frank: Could I help you with my answer?

Comment: Yes. I have zero experience using PHP and the task sounds daunting. When the put request is made I am given a request with this [example](https://www.aftership.com/notifications/54ab6ca6f6407c1f57bb5c3f) It would be convent to send that entire string to my iOS app. This is an old request, a new one has a device token ID in the `customFields` dictionary. If I could send that string to the device that would be great! If nothing else just the tracking number and slug would suffice.

Comment: Great. Nice I could help you. Please remember to accept my answer and reward the bounty :-) I'll keep on chatting with you to get your problem completely (not only the OQ) solved! Can you please send the request to pastebin or similar? I don't have an after ship account and can't access this notification. Theres a chance to that with a few lines PHP I could write for you (if it's not too much)

Comment: im wanted to say: Theres is chance that it is doable with just a few lines of PHP, I could write it for you, if it's not too much. Have you any experience with any server side programming languages or running a web server? Maybe you can use something different from PHP

Comment: And please review my edit, I added some information on the iOS implementation.

Comment: This question is very broad. It sounds like you're just asking how to implement the server side of APN. There are tutorials online.

Answer (score 2):

A webhook is basically a service **you** provide for external applications to connect to. For example MailChimp (a newsletter service) uses webhooks to notify you when a scheduled newsletter is sent. It can be anything that responds to TCP connections so you could also write a server in C or similar.

I set up a server that provides a webhook (a simple PHP file) that the MailChimp server queries via HTTP. Then I use the POSTed information within PHP to generate and deliver the APN myself.

I wrote a custom PHP class for this, but you could use the very popular [ApnsPHP](https://code.google.com/p/apns-php/) class. You definitely have to run your own server, managed server or any web hosting service that supports PHP.

In my case I also implemented all of this as a WordPress plugin for a custom theme for one of my clients.

The URL you have to enter in the field of the API provider is the URL to your PHP script (or any other script or server program).

You would first need to register the device for push notifications in `-[NSApplicationDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]`. This will make your device receive notifications for your app.

The two methods you mentioned are used to process the information received.

This topic is really broad so I can't give you a complete implementation. But I would recommend [this tutorial on raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1), there is sample code included and also a server side PHP script. This tutorial did teach me a lot about APNs.

Answer (score 0):

When they say that they don't support push notifications, I assume they mean it, so you won't use those 2 methods... What they mean is that in whatever method you have to get data from the webhook, you'll need to manually present the push somehow (eg. UIAlertView)

Comment: The general idea is that when an update is made it is posted to the webhook then the webhook' script sends out a notification to the application which in turn will run `didReceiveRemoteNotification`

Comment: I guess my confusion is who's getting the webhook update? Your client or a server script? If it's the first, as I said, you'll need to manually show the notification yourself, if it's the second, you'll need to make your script send a real push notification trough apple's APNS, here's a good starting point https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Comment: A WebHook is always related to servers. If a client would connect to a web hook, I would rather name it "REST API" (even if it does just a few tasks). You cannot connect to an iOS-Based server from the internet (just LAN). So there shouldn't be any confusion about.

Comment: I've seen people try weirder things than that